# read position based txt

Tags: python, parsing, txt

I have a txt file that I read into a list of strings in which each item of the list is a data sample of 3 variables `(A,B,C)`

```
txt = [
     '001   0198110',
     '0020130198110',
     '0030132198110',
]
```

A separate support dataframe that looks like this

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[[1,3,"A"],[4,3,"B"],[7,6,"C"]],columns=["Position","Lenght","Name"])

df
       Position   Lenght    Name
    0   1         3         A
    1   4         3         B
    2   7         6         C
```

indicates how I should read the txt. For example the variable A starts at position 1 of each record and its length is 3.

Taking as an example only the first record

```
'001   0198110'
```

we have that `A=001` `B=empty->NaN` `C=0198110`

What would be an efficient way (considering that the txt file is 50k lines and contains +600 variables) to create the expected parsed dataframe

```
    A   B       C
0   1   NaN     198110
1   2   13      198110
2   3   13     2198110
```

I can use a for loop, but perhaps there is a better way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [`pd.read_fwf`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_fwf.html#pandas-read-fwf):

```py
from io import StringIO

txt = ["001    198110", "0020130198110", "0030132198110"]

df = pd.DataFrame(
    data=[[1, 3, "A"], [4, 4, "B"], [7, 6, "C"]],
    columns=["Position", "Lenght", "Name"],
)


x = pd.read_fwf(
    StringIO("\n".join(txt)),
    widths=df.Lenght,
    header=None,
)
x.columns = df.Name.to_list()
print(x)
```

Prints:

```
   A      B       C
0  1    NaN  198110
1  2  130.0  198110
2  3  132.0  198110
```

---

Note: I changes the `txt` list/`df` dataframe:

- First value of `txt` to `"001    198110"`
- Length of `B` to `4` in `df`

Prints:

Comment: great! thanks! you also spotted an error in my expected output... I corrected it in the question, but your answer is correct

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to recommend optimizations without knowing what the data usually looks like. My first two approaches would be those:

If there are a lot of similarities like C, you could look into running a diff first, so you know the ranges where you can copy without rechecking over all the files.

If there is a lot of overlap between variables, you could sort them by starting position and write multiple at the same time, which should also be easier on memory than random accesses

Comment: not sure I understood your answer, could you provide some code?